# IE hosted windows control with dependent assemblies

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, controls

I am working with a windows forms user control that needs to be hosted in Internet Explorer.  Info about the technique I am trying to duplicate can be found [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030610.htm) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jdivine/UserControlInInternetExplorer11172005231420PM/UserControlInInternetExplorer.aspx).

However, the control fails to load in the browser because it relies on multiple other dependant dll’s.  Is there a way to get the dependent assemblies to be downloaded with the control?

Comment: I'm aware that Silverlight (or just starting with a Web Control instead of Windows Control) would be a better solution.  However, for this project the Windows Control hoseted in IE is desired.  Is there any way to get the dependent assemblies to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also use this method to host WinForms-Controls on a html page. I found out that the internetexplorer tries to find the dependant dll in the root of the webserver. Cave: the internetexplorer does not look for the dlls in the root of the webapplication.

Let me tell you a example.
I built a audio-recorder control Recorder.dll. This control uses RecLib.dll.
I have a WebApp named Recorder on my local IIS and use the dll within http//localhost/Recorder/default.aspx
The classid points to "localhost/Recorder/Recorder.dll#..."
I have put my Recorder.dll to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Recorder\Recorder.dll.
Then I have to put the RecLib.dll to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\RecLib.dll.
This is because the IE tries to find the Librariy at http//localhost/Reclib.dll

Hope I could make things clearer to you.